# Format Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#

I created a player class and I am trying to use my player class to update a player for my menu driven player program. I want to be able to have the user enter a player number and ask if they want to update the player assists and goals then display the updated player information and if the player doesn't exist then it would display the message player does not exist. When I go to update a player I keep getting the error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. I am not sure on how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
static void ProcessUpdate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
    Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
{       
    int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
    string answer, answer2;
    if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number");
        number = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);

        if (playerindex != -1)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} currently has {1} goals and {3} assists", players[playerindex].Number,
                    players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEdit Goals?: Y/N");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Goal total");
                goals = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\nEdit Assists?: Y/N");
                answer2 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer2.Equals("Y"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Assists total");
                    assists = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    players[playerindex].LastName = lastName;
                    players[playerindex].FirstName = firstName;
                    players[playerindex].Goals = goals;
                    players[playerindex].Assists = assists;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
                     players[playerindex].Number, players[playerindex].FirstName, players[playerindex].LastName,
                     players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
                    Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Updated!");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
    }
}
```

> This is the line where the error happens

```
Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} currently has {1} goals and {3} assists", players[playerindex].Number,
                        players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `{2}` instead of `{3}` here:

```
"\nUpdate Player: Player {0} currently has {1} goals and {3} assists"
```

The meaning of the error is simply that you're asking for a value at index 3, which you didn't pass in.